Calculate SUMPRODUCT with multiple column criteria and one row criteria (with empty columns and text columns in the data range)
  |   A   |B|C |D|    E     |F|    G   |   H  |   I  |   J  |K|   L   |    M   |   N    |   
--|-------|-|--|-|----------|-|--------|------|------|------|-|-------|--------|--------|--
1 |       | |  | |   ratio  | | tested | 2023 | 2024 | 2025 | |       |        |        |
2 |       | |  | |          | |        |      |      |      | |       |        |        |
3 |       | |  | |Prod.Line1| |        |      |      |      | |RowCrit|ColCrit1|ColCrit2|      
4 |Brand A| |P1| |    7%    | |   yes  |  500 |   70 |   60 | |  2024 | Brand A|   P1   | 
5 |Brand A| |P2| |    8%    | |   yes  |  100 |   47 |  300 | |       | Brand D|   P4   |     
6 |Brand A| |P2| |   10%    | |   yes  |  800 |   21 |  200 | |       |        |        |     
7 |Brand B| |P1| |    5%    | |   yes  |   90 |   56 |  150 | |       |        |        |           
8 |Brand C| |P4| |    3%    | |   no   |   45 |  700 |  790 | |       |        |        |                 
9 |Brand C| |P2| |    8%    | |   no   |  600 |  150 |   40 | | Result|  191.5 |        |            
10|       | |  | |Subtotal  | |        |      |      |      | |       |        |        |
11|       | |  | |          | |        |      |      |      | |       |        |        |
12|       | |  | |Prod.Line2| |        |      |      |      | |       |        |        |               
13|Brand D| |P1| | 12%      | |   yes  |  900 |   90 |  980 | |       |        |        |                       
14|Brand D| |P1| | 20%      | |   yes  |  125 |  854 |  726 | |       |        |        |            
15|Brand D| |P3| | 19%      | |   yes  |   70 |  860 |  614 | |       |        |        |            
16|Brand D| |P4| |  2%      | |   yes  |  842 |  250 |   85 | |       |        |        |            
17|Brand E| |P4| |  6%      | |   no   |  300 |  324 |  450 | |       |        |        |  
18|       | |  | |Subtotal  | |        |      |      |      | |       |        |        |
19|       | |  | |          | |        |      |      |      | |       |        |        |
          


I want to calculate the SUMPRODUCT by multiplying the values from Column E with the corresponding values in Column H:J. 
The SUMPRODUCT formula should also consider the filters for the Row in Cell L4 and the Column in Range M4:M5 and Range N4:N5.
In the example above the result is:
Cell M9 = 7%x70 + 12%x90 + 20%x854 + 2%x250 = 191.5


With reference to the answers in this question I tried to apply this solution:
=LET(
    a, IF(
        COUNTA($M$4:$M$5)=0,
        N(ISNUMBER(ROW($A$2:$A$19))),
        COUNTIF($M$4:$M$5,$A$2:$A$19)
    ),
    b, IF(
        COUNTA($N$4:$N$5)=0,
        N(ISNUMBER(ROW($C$2:$C$19))),
        COUNTIF($N$4:$N$5,$C$2:$C$19)
    ),
    c, CHOOSECOLS($A$2:$J$19,XMATCH($E$1,$A$1:$J$1),XMATCH($L$4,$A$1:$J$1)),
    SUM(a*b*CHOOSECOLS(c,1)*CHOOSECOLS(c,2))
)

However, it returns #VALUE as result. 
As far as I can tell this is caused by the Headers Prod.Line1 and Prod.Line 2 in Cell E3 and Cell E12.
Do you have any idea how to change the formula to make it work?

Is this related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78537715/using-a-list-range-of-multiple-column-and-row-critiera-in-filter-formula ? because it looks like you can just filter column E based on col criteria, filter column H:J based on row and col criteria, and then do the sumproduct????

With reference to the comment from rachel in this question the solution is:
=SUMPRODUCT(LET(a, COUNTIF(M4:M6,A3:A19),b,COUNTIF(N4:N6,C3:C19),FILTER(FILTER(E3:J19,(E1:J1=L4),""),IFS(SUM(a)=0,b,SUM(b)=0,α,1,a*b),"")),LET(a, COUNTIF(M4:M6,A3:A19),b,COUNTIF(N4:N6,C3:C19),FILTER(E3:E19,IFS(SUM(a)=0,b,SUM(b)=0,α,1,a*b),"")))


try this, it is same with the other one posted earlier yesterday, do share feedback: =LET(α, A2:J17,δ, COUNTIFS(M4:M6,TAKE(α,,1),M4:M6,"<>"),ε, COUNTIFS(N4:N6,INDEX(α,,3),N4:N6,"<>"),φ, IFS(SUM(δ)=0,ε,SUM(ε)=0,δ,1,δ*ε),Σ, CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(α, (IF(SUM(φ)=0,SEQUENCE(ROWS(α))^0,φ))*(1-ISERR(--INDEX(α,,5))),0),5,XMATCH(L4,A1:J1)),SUM(TAKE(Σ,,1)*TAKE(Σ,,-1)))

This works on my end based on the conditions provided:


• Formula used in cell M8
=LET(
     α, A2:J17,
     δ, COUNTIFS(M4:M6,TAKE(α,,1),M4:M6,"<>"),
     ε, COUNTIFS(N4:N6,INDEX(α,,3),N4:N6,"<>"),
     φ, IFS(SUM(δ)=0,ε,SUM(ε)=0,δ,1,δ*ε),
     Σ, CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(α, (IF(SUM(φ)=0,SEQUENCE(ROWS(α))^0,φ))*(1-ISERR(--INDEX(α,,5))),0),5,XMATCH(L4,A1:J1)),
     SUM(TAKE(Σ,,1)*TAKE(Σ,,-1)))


Based on my original solution Calculate SUMPRODUCT with multiple column criteria and one row criteria (with empty columns in the data range)

Test Case One: --> When ColCrit1 is empty


Test Case Two: --> When ColCrit2 is empty


Test Case Three: --> When ColCrit1 & ColCrit2 both empty



Try this: (you might need to change ; to , as a function value separator- it is region specific)
=SUMPRODUCT((H1:J1=L4)*(A4:A17=M4)*(C4:C17=N4)*(I4:I17)*IF(ISNUMBER(E4:E17);E4:E17;0)+(H1:J1=L4)*(A4:A17=M5)*(C4:C17=N5)*(I4:I17)*IF(ISNUMBER(E4:E17);E4:E17;0))

